# How to change the app name displayed by "sign in with apple"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, apple-sign-in

I still can't find how to modify this text, it is neither my project name nor my targets name.

The solution I found online is to modify [Identifiers]->[Services IDs]->[Description] in Apple's developer backend. But this doesn't work in my case. This method is suitable for integrating Apple login in **web pages**, but not for **native code**.

So, what should I do?

[image]